# Issue with Android IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent

I am running a simple fql query inside the onHandleIntent() method of Intentservice . Dont know what the problem is , the query part is not getting executed only . here is my onHandleIntent() method

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{

    System.out.println("inside service method now");
    String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, username, online_presence, status FROM user WHERE uid = 100001024732884";

      Bundle params = new Bundle();
      params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
      Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Request request = new Request(session,
              "/fql",                         
              params,                         
              HttpMethod.GET,                 
              new Request.Callback(){         
                  public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    System.out.println("inside the service now 4444");
                      Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());
                  }                  
          }); 
          Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
}
```

Only first statement gets printed.

When i put same code in my MainActivity it works fine but inside IntentService it stops working . I am starting the service on a buttonclick.

Comment: You must try to catch error first. This method must be throwing some error. Use try catch in method and catch the error. Then you may be able to solve the problem.

Comment: You mean only `inside the service now 4444` gets printed?

Comment: no , only the 1st print statement is getting executed.

Comment: the whole inner class is not getting executed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that IntentService will be finished and destroyed before your callback is called since it is running asynchronously.  Instead of using a callback to get the Response, try using this instead.

```
  Bundle params = new Bundle();
  params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
  Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
  Request request = new Request(session,
          "/fql",                         
          params,                         
          HttpMethod.GET);
  Response response = request.executeBatchAndWait();
```